# HDInsight How Many VM's required?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

On this page, they mentioned what minimum server required. But didn't mention how many VM required. For example minimum how many head nodes required and how many worker nodes required for HBASE? Please advice
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Azure HDInsight, each cluster type may contain different types of nodes that have a specific purpose in the cluster. The following table summarizes these node types.

[image].

Each cluster type has its own number of nodes, terminology for nodes, and default VM size. In the following table, the number of nodes for each node type is in parentheses. The scale-out capabilities (e.g., adding VM nodes to increase processing capabilities) for each cluster type are indicated in the node count as (1+) and in the diagram as Worker 1...Worker N.

For **Interactive Hive:**

[image]

For **HBase**:

[image]

For more details, refer [Azure HDInsight Architecture](https://github.com/ZoinerTejada/hdinsight-docs/blob/master/hdinsight-architecture.md#hdinsight-architecture).